# Не удалось найти ресурсы, соответствующие указанной культуре или нейтральной культуре

Tags: c#, wpf, локализация

Локализую WPF-приложение так как указано здесь:

https://habrahabr.ru/post/274477/

На этой странице архив с примером. Из архива скопированы файлы в мой проект и перенесён код.

```
xmlns:globalization="clr-namespace:System.Globalization;assembly=mscorlib"
xmlns:l="clr-namespace:WpfLocalization.Localization"
xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
xmlns:localglobalization="clr-namespace:WpfLocalization"

mc:Ignorable="d" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type={x:Type localglobalization:MainViewModel}}"

<MenuItem Header="{l:Localization Key=File}" >
```

.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Реализация поставщика локализованных строк через ресурсы приложения
    /// </summary>
    public class ResxLocalizationProvider : ILocalizationProvider
    {
        private IEnumerable<CultureInfo> _cultures;

        public object Localize(string key)
        {
//здесб ошибка//При этом key=File
            return Strings.ResourceManager.GetObject(key);
        }

        public IEnumerable<CultureInfo> Cultures => _cultures ?? (_cultures = new List<CultureInfo>
        {
            new CultureInfo("ru-RU"),
            new CultureInfo("en-US"),
        });
    }
}
```

> Дополнительные сведения: Не удалось найти ресурсы, соответствующие
>   указанной культуре или нейтральной культуре.  Проверьте правильность
>   внедрения или связывания "WpfLocalization.Resources.Strings.resources"
>   со сборкой "ProgramMy" во время компиляции, или убедитесь, что все
>   необходимые сопутствующие сборки полностью подписаны и могут быть
>   загружены.

Что может быть не так перенесено? В чём может быть ошибка?

```
public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //for locale manager
            LocalizationManager.Instance.LocalizationProvider = new ResxLocalizationProvider();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено пересозданием файлов ресурсов

Answer (score 4):

Пересоздание конечно хорошо, но существуют два распространенных решения этой проблемы описанные тут [Ссылка на статью](http://www.devowl.net/2017/12/csharp-MissingManifestResourceException-could-not-find-any-resources-appropriate-for-thespecified-culture-or-the-neutral-culture.html). Тут я перечислю их:

1. Правая кнопка по файлу ресусра в студии -> нажать на **"Run Custom Tool"**
2. Проверить, что в свойствах ресурса **"Build Action"** стоит как **"Embedded Resource"**

Answer (score 0):

у меня такая ошибка возникла, когда я в начала класса формы добавил еще один объект.
Например у меня было такое:

```
namespace ItvTelegram
{
public class Lad
{
    public string firstName;
    public string lastName;
}

public partial class Form1 : Form, IMessageFilter
{
```

есл убрать опимание класса  class Lad то ошибка исчезнет